# Which is the best numerical method to find solutions ( discontinuous in general) of the following non linear ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to write a Fortran program (or better I d like to use an available library if existing) to find the solution y(x) of the following non linear Ordinary Differential Equation:

$\dfrac{df_1(y,x)}{dx}+f_2(y,x)\dfrac{df_4(x)}{dx}+f_3(y,x)\dfrac{df_5(x)}{dx}=f_6(y,x)$

If I substitute the expressions of the functions f1, f2, f4, f5 and f6 my ODE reads:

$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(    \dfrac{1}{g_2(x)y} + g_2(x)y^2 \right)+ y^2 \dfrac{dg_2(x)}{dx}+g_2(x)y \dfrac{dg_1(x)}{dx}= \dfrac{1}{g_2(x)y^a}$

where g1 and g2 are general functions of $x$ that can assume any form, and $a$ a constant between 1 and 2. Note that I cannot expand the terms in f1 by the product rule ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule ) since y, g1 and g2 are in general DISCONTINUOUS and therefore not differentiable.

I said "numerical" cause I guess no analytical tools are available in this case. I have a bigger fortran program in which I have to call a subroutine that solves this ODE, therefore if you are aware of an existing numerical library (Fortran, but also C++ would work) that would be a great hint. 
Thank you a lot in advance
A.

Comment: What is the concept of solution here? I must admit that discontinuous solutions to an ODE is unknown territory to me.

Comment: Here is a paper that proves Uniqueness for discontinuous O.D.E. http://www.math.psu.edu/shen_w/PS/ODEClaw.pdf

Comment: Sorry that was for a discountinuous source term. Here is a paper that deals with weak solutions (i.e. discontinuous) for a ODE http://www.math.psu.edu/shen_w/PS/ODEClaw.pdf . But without entering the mathematical detail..I would have liked to know if there is a good numerical method to solve this.

Comment: Ah. Not discontinuous solutions at all, then. From the intro to the paper: “Solutions are understood in the sense of Carathéodory, i.e. as **absolutely continuous** functions which satisfy (1) almost everywhere.” (My emphasis.) The core idea of weak solutions is that the *derivatives* may be discontinuous, not the solution itself. (Though in PDE theory, the solution itself may have discontinuities.)

Comment: Maybe the paper I linked was not the best example, my bad, but I am sure that this equation admits discontinuous solutions, cause it is the steady state of an hyperbolic 1-dimensional PDE that has discontinuous steady solutions. I just cant find a numerical algorithm that solves the equation in this form...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what to do,
so first, I'll rewrite
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(    \dfrac{1}{g_2(x)y} + g_2(x)y^2 \right)+ y^2 \dfrac{dg_2(x)}{dx}+g_2(x)y \dfrac{dg_1(x)}{dx}= \dfrac{1}{g_2(x)y^a}$$
as
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{1}{g(x)y} + g(x)y^2 \right)+ y^2 \dfrac{dg(x)}{dx}+g(x)y \dfrac{dh(x)}{dx}= \dfrac{1}{g(x)y^a}$$
or, even more lazily,
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{1}{gy} + gy^2 \right)+ y^2 \dfrac{dg}{dx}+gy \dfrac{dh}{dx}= \dfrac{1}{gy^a}$$
or
$$\left(\dfrac{1}{gy}\right)' + (gy^2)'+ y^2 g'+gy h'= \dfrac{1}{gy^a}$$

Since
$\left(\dfrac1{gy}\right)'
=-\dfrac{(gy)'}{g^2y^2}
=-\dfrac{gy'+g'y}{g^2y^2}
=-\dfrac{gy'+g'y}{g^2y^2}
=-\dfrac{y'}{gy^2}-\dfrac{g'}{g^2y}
$,
the equation becomes
$$-\dfrac{y'}{gy^2}-\dfrac{g'}{g^2y} + g'y^2+2gyy'+ y^2 g'+gy h'= \dfrac{1}{gy^a}$$

Collecting the $y'$ terms, I get
$$y' \left(-\dfrac{1}{gy^2}+2gy \right)
-\dfrac{g'}{g^2y}+ g'y^2+ y^2 g'+gy h'-\dfrac{1}{gy^a}
=0
$$

Multiplying by $y^2$, this becomes
$$y' \left(-\dfrac{1}{g}+2gy^3 \right)
-\dfrac{g'y}{g^2}+ g'y^4+ y^4 g'+gy^3 h'-\dfrac{y^{2-a}}{g}
=0
$$

Since $g'y^4$ occurs twice
(is this an error?), this is
$$y' \left(-\dfrac{1}{g}+2gy^3 \right)
-\dfrac{g'y}{g^2}+ 2g'y^4+gy^3 h'-\dfrac{y^{2-a}}{g}
=0
$$

At this point I have no idea what to do,
except to note that
there is no $h$,
only $h'$, 
and wonder if that makes any difference.

I don't know if this is any help,
but I keyed it in, so,
instead of discarding it,
I'll post it.

Comment: Thanks for that. Sorry I forgot to mention that also g1 and g2 are in general discontinuous (I amended the text above) therefore the terms in f1 cannot be expanded by using the product rule as you did.

Comment: If they are piecewise differentiable, you can differentiate them there.